# Express/Mongoose - Error: Argument passed in must be a single String of 12 bytes

Tags: javascript, arrays, express, mongoose

I'm receiving an array from an Angular service and passing it to Mongoose/Express. I'm trying to query ObjectIds and retrieve all results but when converting my array to ObectIds I receive: Error: Argument passed in must be a single String of 12 bytes or a string of 24 hex characters.

The array I'm passing is:
Array(6) [ "6104842e42c23e6d215651ca", "6104844e42c23e6d215651cd", "610484e042c23e6d215651e1", "610484bf42c23e6d215651d2", "6104838a42c23e6d215651c4", "610483a342c23e6d215651c6" ]

```
router.get('/favorite-image/:id', (req, res) => {
  const ObjectId = require('mongodb').ObjectId;
  var idArray = [req.params.id];
  var ids = idArray.map(function(el){ return ObjectId(el)});    
  gfs.files.find({'_id': {$in: ids}}, (err, files) => {
    //check if files exist
    if (!files || files.length == 0) {
      return res.status(404).json({
        err: "No files exist"
      });
    };
    //file exist
    console.log(res.json(files))
    return res.json(files)
  });
});
```

I have also tried a forEach loop but that didn't work either:

```
idArray.forEach(function (el){
  String(el);
  ObjectId(el);
})
```

Any assistance is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Are you saying `req.params.id` is an array? Then `idArray` is an array of arrays, and mongoose likes to get passed strings not arrays. Can you please add the output you get when putting `console.log(typeof el, el)` in the loop, to clarify this?

Comment: I receive: string 6104842e42c23e6d215651ca

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to use map instead of forEach

```
router.get('/favorite-image/',  (req, res) => { 
    //console.log(req.params.id)
  const ObjectId = require('mongodb').ObjectId;
  var g = req.params.id.split(',');
    let mid = g.map(function(el){String(el);ObjectId(el); return el});
    //console.log(mid);
  gfs.files.find(
     
     {_id: {$in: mid}}).toArray ((err, files) => { 
        // check if files exist
    console.log('here');
        if (!files || files.length == 0) {
      console.log('fail')
          return res.status(404).json({
            err: "No files exist"
          });
        };
        //file exist
        // console.log(res.json(files));
    console.log('success')
        return res.json(files)
      });
    });
```